# Rails - datetimepicker field not updating in database

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker, datetimepicker

I'm using the jquery datetimepicker plugin on my site for selecting datetimes. On a form I change the start_at and end_at time (both use datetimepicker) of a meeting form which when submitted post this..

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ugju0DDRlcMkg5u2FtTDj8upZNV16vXgd7RLqzgNmLE=", "meeting"=>{"organizer_id"=>"2", "state"=>"draft", "title"=>"testing endtime", "message"=>"wtf!", "start_at"=>"Thu, Feb 07, 03:00PM", "end_at"=>"Thu, Feb 7, 4:00PM",...
```

Clearly both start_at and end_at are being passed. The strange thing is that start_at gets updated in the database, but end_at does not. Both were changed on the form. Any ideas?

From the log..

```
UPDATE "meetings" SET "start_at" = '2013-02-07 23:00:00.000000', "updated_at" = '2013-02-06 06:44:16.922129' WHERE "meetings"."id" = 6
```

My datetimepicker settings..

```
  $('.date_time_select').live('click', function() {
    $(this).datetimepicker({
      ampm: true,
      dateFormat: "D, M d,",
      timeFormat: "h:mmTT",
      minDate: 0
    }).focus();
  });
```

my controller..

```
def update
  @meeting = current_user.meetings.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @meeting.update_attributes(params[:meeting])
      format.html { redirect_to @meeting, :notice => "Meeting was successfully updated" }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

And schema..

```
t.datetime "start_at"
t.datetime "end_at"
```

Comment: If your request has the right parameters, it's not the datepicker's fault; it's something in your controller. Can you post that? And also the relevant part of schema.rb?

Comment: sadly there's nothing much happening in the controller. Added the stuff you asked.

Comment: What is in your Meeting model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time format should be all one format.

Notice the time format of `start_at` is not the same as that of `end_at`.

```
start_at=>Thu, Feb 07, 03:00PM

end_at=>Thu, Feb 7, 4:00PM
```

So if your form field is like the following:

```
<%= f.text_field :end_at, :class => "ended-at-datetime" %>
```

You can set it explicitly in your `application.js` like this:

```
$('.ended-at-datetime').datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd ', timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss ', ampm: true});
```

And the same for `start_at` also.

I could be wrong but I haven't seen it separated.

I know if the format is not right it will not go into a database.